# What is the best approach to list items geo-nearly after getting all the details from another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am developing something in mongodb/mongoose. I have such document
`{"organizer": "Some University", venues: [{"id": "1", "location": {"type": "Point": "coordinates":[lon, lat]}}]}`

then another one for events 
`{"event": "Event 1", "venues":["1", "2"]...}`

I want to get full details for the venues before having a geoNear query based on the current location of the end-user.

I have gone through different tutorials on this. But, with no luck. Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide example of expecting result to understand what you are trying to do...

To join 2 collections (`$lookup`) where condition is not 1 to 1 fields, you can use Uncorrelated subquery with `let` / `pipeline` fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$venues"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "event",
      let: {
        venues_id: "$venues.id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$$venues_id",
                "$venues"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "events"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zmDIjyj7IqS)